# Request bigger than 4k

Tags: apache, tomcat, cookies, request

I'd like to know how to avoid a 500 ise in a java application (tomcat) when I get a request bigger than 4K. What happens is that browser or apache (still didn't understand who) truncate the request size to 4K and Tomcat raise an exception

> An exception or error occurred in the container during the request
>   processing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Control character in
>   cookie value or attribute.

As far as I've red on the web the request is toasted so there is no way to handle the error in Java. Since I have no control on the request size (dozens of cookies from statistic tools with a lifetime longer than 6 months and set on "/" domain)

Is there a way to say apache "hey, if the request size is bigger than 3K redirect to this page", and in this page I will erase all cookies. Do you have any better idea?

Regards,
Carlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a workaround using a regexp we get the request size and then send to a custom page that erase cookies via js in order to avoid future 500 ise

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} .{3072,}
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /clearcookie.html [L,PT]
```

Hope this helps,
regards.

Carlo